# How to resolve configuration objects lang code differences?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

The default language for my site is Arabic, but the administration bits are in English. This means that for now, the only needed translations are those of labels and the interface.

Earlier I tried to translate some of my content types and found most of them configured like this:

> English
> Arabic
> None (original)  Edit

With this message above:

> The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot
> be translated:
>
> - node.type.person: en
> - core.base_field_override.node.person.title: ar

I tried changing the language settings for the content type but the language remained set to 'None'. Any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is connected to this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223665/how-to-change-default-language-for-configuration-entities

Comment: I opened an issue about that https://www.drupal.org/node/2909935

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure I can help but I had a similar issue.
After enabling translation for pages, I got a similar error in admin/structure/types/manage/page/translate:

```
The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot be translated:

node.type.page: en
core.base_field_override.node.page.title: pt
```

I think this happened because I was by mistake in /pt/admin (?).

Anyway, I fixed this (in my case, I always want en), by running the command:

```
$ drush cset core.base_field_override.node.page.title langcode en
```

Comment: I am going to try this later. Any idea about what caused your case?

Comment: As I mentioned, I think this happened because I was by mistake in /pt/admin while configuring the title field. Usually I work with the en version (/admin) and this does not occur.

Good luck and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Related topic in Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2909935

Comment: Thanks @dxvargas for the tip! Also to speed-up process I've used bulk search/replace in files in phpStorm with a next filters:
- search: `^langcode\: und`
- replace: `langcode: en`
- file mask: `field.storage.*`