# How do i change the button text "subscribe", from the "simplenews" module, in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, emails

I'm very new to drupal and programming.

I simply want to change some text on the simplenews "subscribe"/"unsubscribe" buttons.

From past questions I understand the only solution is programmatically? I've seen the hook_page_alter() method mentioned but I am not experienced enough to get it to work.

This is my poor attempt at utilizing it:

```
 function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'simplenews_subscriptions_block') {
       $form['New button text'] = array(
           '#markup' => '<p> New button text </p>',
       )    
    } 
}
```

Comment: There are solutions without code, in D7 you had the string overrides and in D8 you can use an english-to-english translation.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. 
It was under admin/config/people/simplenews/settings/subscriber/fields/ for anyone else looking for it. 


If you get the error message "The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot be translated:" look at this thread for the solution for that: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223665/how-to-change-default-language-for-configuration-entities

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer

Comment: I just posted the above comment as an answer @Matt

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out due to 4k4's comment

Basically you can translate it english-to-english under /admin/config/people/simplenews/settings/subscriber/fields/
It's a part of the configuration translation module.

If you get the error message "The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot be translated:" look at this thread for the solution for that: [How to change default language for configuration entities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223665/how-to-change-default-language-for-configuration-entities)